# Why do bytes exist? Why don't we just use bits?

Tags: byte, hardware, bit

A byte consists of 8 bits on most systems.

A byte typically represents the smallest data type a programmer may use. Depending on language, the data types might be called `char` or `byte`.

There are some types of data (booleans, small integers, etc) that could be stored in fewer bits than a byte. Yet using less than a byte is not supported by any programming language I know of (natively).

Why does this minimum of using 8 bits to store data exist? Why do we even need bytes? Why don't computers just use increments of bits (1 or more bits) rather than increments of bytes (multiples of 8 bits)?

Just in case anyone asks: I'm not worried about it. I do not have any specific needs. I'm just curious.

Comment: Some systems use other byte sizes instead of 8 bits

Comment: @M.M True. But most modern systems use 8 from what I understand. Regardless of the number used on any specific system, my question remains: what is the reason for bytes?

Comment: Imagine life without abstraction.

Comment: Why do we have feet and not just inches for everything?

Comment: @JackRyan This isn't about equivalent ways of defining the same thing. A Boolean stored in 1 bit is different than a Boolean stored in 8 bits.

Comment: Yup, but you're probably reading in 32s or 64s, so who cares, really?

Comment: Now that it's the 21st century @JackRyan it's about time you become comfortable with the metric system. =)

Comment: This seems off-topic.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I didn't mean to post an off-topic question. I recently watched a presentation (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xnfnv6WT1Ng) that talked about the benefits of data density with respect to CPU throughput bottlenecks. It got me wondering if things could be even better. I think this is an objective programming question that should have a definitive answer. Please let me know if you have any ideas on how I could make it better.

Comment: @TomDworzanski: Nope. There are FPGA implementations and some DSPs which use other units of access. Sometimes 9 bits (handy for pixel-processing), sometimes 24 bits, sometimes 16 bits.

Comment: Read about the TMS34010/20. They used bit-addresses.

Comment: @JackRyan: Most parts of the world are very happy they have neither inches nor feet, but use some very strange measuring system, called "metric system". IIRC, this is also official US standard, but it is so weird they refuse to use in every day-usage. Just imagine: units are based on factor 10 - everywhere - not completely irregular factors. How bizarre.

Comment: @TomDworzanski: It's a discussion question. It's not a question about some actual piece of code. It's a decent enough question with a clear answer; I'm just not sure it belongs _here_. :)

Comment: Anyway, you _could_ have a one-bit machine architecture, but it would be quite obviously be a complete pain in the arse.

Answer (score 11):

because at the hardware level memory is naturally organized into addressable chunks. Small chunks means that you can have fine grained things like 4 bit numbers; large chunks allow for more efficient operation (typically a CPU moves things around in 'chunks' or multiple thereof). IN particular larger addressable chunks make for bigger address spaces. If I have chunks that are 1 bit then an address range of 1 - 500 only covers 500 bits whereas 500 8 bit chunks cover 4000 bits.

Note - it was not always 8 bits. I worked on a machine that thought in 6 bits. (good old octal)

Answer (score 7):

Paper tape (~1950's) was 5 or 6 holes (bits) wide, maybe other widths.
Punched cards (the newer kind) were 12 rows of 80 columns.

1960s:
B-5000 - 48-bit "words" with 6-bit characters
CDC-6600 -- 60-bit words with 6-bit characters
IBM 7090 -- 36-bit words with 6-bit characters
There were 12-bit machines; etc.

1970-1980s, "micros" enter the picture:
Intel 4004 - 4-bit chunks
8008, 8086, Z80, 6502, etc - 8 bit chunks
68000 - 16-bit words, but still 8-bit bytes
486 - 32-bit words, but still 8-bit bytes
today - 64-bit words, but still 8-bit bytes
future - 128, etc, but still 8-bit bytes

Get the picture?  Americans figured that characters could be stored in only 6 bits.
Then we discovered that there was more in the world than just English.
So we floundered around with 7-bit ascii and 8-bit EBCDIC.

Eventually, we decided that 8 bits was good enough for all the characters we would ever need.  ("We" were not Chinese.)

The IBM-360 came out as the dominant machine in the '60s-70's; it was based on an 8-bit byte.  (It sort of had 32-bit words, but that became less important than the all-mighty byte.

It seemed such a waste to use 8 bits when all you really needed 7 bits to store all the characters you ever needed.

IBM, in the mid-20th century "owned" the computer market with 70% of the hardware and software sales.  With the 360 being their main machine, 8-bit bytes was the thing for all the competitors to copy.

Eventually, we realized that other languages existed and came up with Unicode/utf8 and its variants.  But that's another story.

Answer (score 2):

Good way for me to write something late on night!

Your points are perfectly valid, however, history will always be that insane intruder how would have ruined your plans long before you were born.

For the purposes of explanation, let's imagine a ficticious machine with an architecture of the name of *Bitel(TM) Inside* or something of the like. The *Bitel* specifications mandate that the Central Processing Unit (CPU, i.e, microprocessor) shall access memory in one-bit units. Now, let's say a given instance of a *Bitel*-operated machine has a memory unit holding 32 billion bits (our ficticious equivalent of a 4GB RAM unit).

Now, let's see why *Bitel, Inc.* got into bankruptcy:

- The binary code of *any* given program would be gigantic (the compiler would have to manipulate *every* single bit!)
- 32-bit addresses would be (even more) limited to hold *just 512MB of memory*. 64-bit systems would be safe (for now...)
- Memory accesses would be literally a deadlock. When the CPU has got all of those 48 bits it needs to process a single `ADD` instruction, the floppy would have already spinned for too long, and you know what happens next...
- Who the **** **really** needs to optimize a single **bit**? (See previous bankruptcy justification).
- If you need to handle single bits, learn to use `bitwise operators`!
- Programmers would go crazy as **both** coffee and RAM get too expensive. At the moment, this is a perfect synonym of apocalypse.
- The C standard is holy and sacred, and it mandates that the minimum addressable unit (i.e, `char`) shall be *at least* 8 bits wide.
- `8` is a perfect power of `2`. (`1` is another one, but meh...)

Comment: I suggest that the C Standard was reflecting the what the hardware was and was headed, not the other way around.  C went through a mess when `int` needed to be promoted from a 16-bit integer to 32 bits.  During that transition, it was too easy to make non-portable code.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it's an issue of addressing. To access individual bits of data, you would need eight times as many addresses (adding 3 bits to each address) compared to using accessing individual bytes. The byte is generally going to be the smallest practical unit to hold a number in a program (with only 256 possible values).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm wondering then: does having 8 times as many addresses cause problems?

Comment: @TomDworzanski I think 8-bit is the natural size. Because 4-bit cannot even hold English alphabet. It's not useful at all. And 16-bit is too big for some data manipulation, e.g. text data.

Comment: @TomDworzanski as I kind of explained but phrased poorly, having 8 times as many addresses requires 3 extra bits of data in an address to determine which bit is being selected. Overall, this would be terribly inefficient, especially considering the bits by themselves are almost useless. Imagine planning a city where every building has eight rooms, and each room has a unique address. If you wanted to identify buildings as a whole, there are seven unneeded addresses per building. This is a similar scenario.

Comment: The same argument was probably used for the old mainframes, which could address only whole words (of 32, 40, 60, etc bits).

Comment: @cshu - For a long time (1950s-1960s), computers were happy to store English in 6-bit pieces (upper case only).

Answer (score 1):

Some CPUs use words to address memory instead of bytes. That's their natural data type, so 16 or 32 bits. If Intel CPUs did that it would be 64 bits.

8 bit bytes are traditional because the first popular home computers used 8 bits. 256 values are enough to do a lot of useful things, while 16 (4 bits) are not quite enough.

And, once a thing goes on for long enough it becomes terribly hard to change. This is also why your hard drive or SSD likely still pretends to use 512 byte blocks. Even though the disk hardware does not use a 512 byte block and the OS doesn't either. (Advanced Format drives have a software switch to disable 512 byte emulation but generally only servers with RAID controllers turn it off.)

Also, Intel/AMD CPUs have so much extra silicon doing so much extra decoding work that the slight difference in 8 bit vs 64 bit addressing does not add any noticeable overhead. The CPU's memory controller is certainly not using 8 bits. It pulls data into cache in long streams and the minimum size is the cache line, often 64 bytes aka 512 bits. Often RAM hardware is slow to start but fast to stream so the CPU reads kilobytes into L3 cache, much like how hard drives read an entire track into their caches because the drive head is already there so why not?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, C and C++ do have native support for [bit-fields](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field).

```
#include <iostream>
struct S {
    // will usually occupy 2 bytes:
    // 3 bits: value of b1
    // 2 bits: unused
    // 6 bits: value of b2
    // 2 bits: value of b3
    // 3 bits: unused
    unsigned char b1 : 3, : 2, b2 : 6, b3 : 2;
};
int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(S) << '\n'; // usually prints 2
}
```

Probably an answer lies in performance and memory alignment, and the fact that (I reckon partly because `byte` is called `char` in C) byte is the smallest part of machine word that can hold a 7-bit ASCII. Text operations are common, so special type for plain text have its gain for programming language.

Comment: When "word boundaries" were a big deal, C compilers were allowed to pad between struct members.  Think of a struct with a `char`, then an `int` generating code for a machine with 16-bit words and no off-boundary accessing.  Example: The Motorola 68000 used by the original Macintoshes.

Answer (score 0):

Why bytes?

What is so special about 8 bits that it deserves its own name?
Computers do process all data as bits, but they prefer to process bits in byte-sized groupings. Or to put it another way: a byte is how much a computer likes to "bite" at once.

The byte is also the smallest addressable unit of memory in most modern computers. A computer with byte-addressable memory can not store an individual piece of data that is smaller than a byte.

What's in a byte?
A byte represents different types of information depending on the context. It might represent a number, a letter, or a program instruction. It might even represent part of an audio recording or a pixel in an image.

[Source](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computers-and-internet/xcae6f4a7ff015e7d:digital-information/xcae6f4a7ff015e7d:bits-and-bytes/a/byte-sized-bits)